# Apache autoindex: turn off hyperlinks?

Tags: configuration, apache-httpd

Is it possible with apache autoindex to have it display the
file listing in a directory, but not have the items 
hyperlinked?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible, thanks to open source code. :)

The easiest way is to edit the Apache2 source file for the `mod_autoindex` module that creates the `html` that is sent to the client. Here is the file you would need to edit <sub>1</sub>:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/branches/2.2.x/modules/generators/mod_autoindex.c

There are 7 places in that file where an anchor tag is created. Simply change those tags to something like `span` tags or turn it into an `ul` and set the text that you want to display to the anchor tag's `href` property.

Recompile the module and reinstall the module. There are several ways to add or remove modules from apache, and the best way depends on which distro you are running.

<sup>1</sup> The actual file depends on what version of Apache you are running and which version on `mod_autolink` you are installing, but this is essentially the right piece of code to hack on.